# Pandas `eval()` doesn't work with `pd.Int64Dtype()`

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with nullable integer type, but I am having trouble using `eval()` with it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())

# This works
2 * df['x']

# But this doesn't
df.eval("2 * x")
# TypeError: Cannot interpret 'Int64Dtype()' as a data type
```

I have pandas 1.2.5.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

EDIT: change the code from multiplying by 100.0 to 2 (an integer) in order to make the issue more clear.

Comment: The `Int64Dtype` is still experimental, and `eval` isn't overly flexible, so you can either avoid eval and just do the multiplication yourself, or ditch the experimental dtype

Comment: @ALollz. The problem is not `Int64Dtype` specifically. The same code with `Int32Dtype` doesn't work. Same for `Int16Dtype` and `Int8Dtype`.

Comment: Can you do `df.eval("100.0 * x.astype('float')")` ? The result type will be `float64` (not `Float64` though)

Comment: @Corralien well yes, all of those dtypes are the experimental **I**ntegerArray, becasue of the capital I (basically a nullable integer). None of those are basic numpy or python dtypes, which is likely the root of the problem being that eval relies on those.

Comment: @AndrejKesely that works in the original MWE, but if I have something like `df.eval("2 * x.astype('float')")` it would cast it to `float` but I'd prefer it to stay as some sort of integer.